# How to hide the Notification drawer in Android OS 3.0 and above?

Tags: android, notifications, android-remoteview

I am working on application having notification system that supports
the OS version from 2.3.3 and above. In android OS less than 3 we have
the option to set the content intent. The whole notification area is
single click-able.

But for the OS 3.0 and above by using Remote-view we have 3 different
button to preform respective actions. By opening the notification
drawer we can click on any button to perform action.

After the button click by default the notification drawer is not going
up(or Hide). Is there any way to hide the notification drawer
programmatic-ally. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that issue with following snippet.
But this is not recommended to use. 
This can be achieved with the help of reflection.
In future this may be deprecated.

void collapseStatusBar(Context context) {
    // Get access to system status bar. This is not public so may be
    // deprecated in the future
    Object service = context.getSystemService("statusbar");

```
Class<?> statusbarManager = null;

try {
    statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.getMessage();
}

// Till 4.1 (JB), StatusBarManager collapse method did the job but from
// 4.2 it's been
// changed to collpasePanels, so perform the job accordingly
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 16) {
    Method collapseMethod = null;

    try {
        collapseMethod = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    collapseMethod.setAccessible(true);

    try {
        collapseMethod.invoke(service);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
} else {
    Method collapsePanelsMethod = null;

    try {
        collapsePanelsMethod = statusbarManager
                .getMethod("collapsePanels");
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
        e1.getMessage();
    }

    collapsePanelsMethod.setAccessible(true);

    try {
        collapsePanelsMethod.invoke(service);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you using something like

```
NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNM.cancelAll();
```

Comment: CancelAll() method will Cancel all previously shown notifications. But our requirement is we are sliding down the notification drawer. Once the button is clicked in that notification we have to slide up that notification drawer. How to do it programmatic-ally..